# Проблема в адаптиве, подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Проблема заключается в следуещем
Когда проверяю используя дебагер хрома(типа как будет смотреться сайт на мобильных устройствах), в правой части вы можете наблюдать пустое место, которое идёт прям до конца сайта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если просто уменьшить окно браузера, то всё работает так, как мне нужно,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увы собственного сервера я не имею, чтобы проверить реальный вид сайта, подскажите, это баг самого дебагера, или же у меня просто лишняя хромосома?

Comment: Если только для тестирования, то можно воспользоваться бесплатным хостингом. Например, [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.ru/)

Comment: Если meta device-width не прописан, то проблема в этом и пропишите. Багов в хромовом дебагере не замечал. Не жалейте пару сотен рублей на небольшой личный сервачок ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из блоков или какой-то элемент в верстке имеет фиксированную ширину, из-за которого это всё и происходит =)

Comment: тоже поначалу так думал, но ни у кого из них не было фиксированой ширины, которая могла бы так сильно растянуть блок

Comment: @Mr.Edinorozhok Добавь html, css код

Comment: вы были правы, действительно несколько блоков имели ширину, что давала такой результат

Comment: @Mr.Edinorozhok У меня частенько всплывает такая проблема =) Отметьте пожалуйста ответ правильным!

Answer (score 1):

Короче ребят, проблема была в очень явной(уже явной для меня) проблеме, у меня внизу стоял блок с margin-right: 50%, он выталкивал блок за пределы body, а я прописал ему transform: translateX(-50%), после того как убрал, всё решилось.